# JS: firebase.init error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined

Tags: firebase, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

Am getting this error after following the steps mentioned in the nativescript-plugin-firebase readme file.

> JS: firebase.init error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of
> undefined

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

but i dont really understand nor do i know how to solve that.

the version of the plugin am using is : 6.4.0
with tns 4.1.2

## EDIT: init code, from app.js

```
var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
firebase.init({ persist: true
    // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
    // see their respective docs.
}).then(
    function (instance) {
    console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
    console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);
```

Comment: show us your init code

Comment: @PhilippSander I added it.

Comment: I finally solved it by installing the plugin manually via the CLI (i initially installed it through NativeScript sidekick) apparently they didnt take in count the fact that some plugins may require some user inputs, to do write specific config file (which nativescript-plugin-firebase),  so by installing it manually i got to provide the user input needed, it got configured and it worked!

Comment: You can answer your own question here and accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by installing the plugin manually via the CLI (i initially installed it through NativeScript sidekick) apparently they didnt take in count the fact that some plugins may require some user inputs, to do write specific config file (which nativescript-plugin-firebase), so by installing it manually i got to provide the user input needed, it got configured and it worked!